# Isogram- a word without repeated letters

Tags: java, sorting

I want to develop a java code to detect a repeated letter in word and print the desired result but mine keeps iterating and i have no idea on how to get about it. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Isogram {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the name: ");

        String car = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        char[] jhd = car.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(jhd);

        for(int ch = 0; ch < jhd.length; ch++){
            try {
                if (jhd[ch] == jhd[ch + 1]) {// || jhd[ch] == jhd[ch]){
                    System.out.print("THis is an Isogram");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Ripu from here");
                }
            } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ae) {
                System.out.println(ae);
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

If u have an adjustment or a better code it will be helpful.

Comment: this might not answer your question but your loop will go out of bounds sooner or later

Comment: 'It's not working' is *not* a valid question

Comment: [Isogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isogram): *An isogram (also known as a "nonpattern word") is a logological term for a word or phrase without a repeating letter.* --- Your code prints `THis is an Isogram` if you find two of the same character next to each other. Problems with that: 1) Opposite of what an isogram is. 2) Checking characters other than letters is wrong. 3) Definition applies to *words*, not entire sentences, and you don't check if what user entered is a single word. 4) "Repeated" doesn't mean "consecutive". `bob` is not an isogram, because it has two `b` letters.

Comment: @Andreas OP's code sorts before checking for consecutive equal letters.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ -- you don't need our help to debug this. I suggest learning to use your IDE's debugger feature ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static String isIsogram(String s){
        String[] ary = s.split("");
        Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(ary));

        if(s.length() == mySet.size()){
            return "Yes!";
        }else{
            return "NO";
        }
    }
```

1. Create an array from the string.
2. Convert array to a List and then create a Set from that List. Set
   keeps only unique values.
3. If set size equals the initial string length then it is an
           isogram. If set is smaller than initial string then there were
           duplicate characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static boolean isIsogram(String str) {

       boolean status = true;
       char [] array = str.toCharArray();
       Character[] charObjectArray = ArrayUtils.toObject(array);
       Map<Character,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

       for (Character i : charObjectArray){
          Integer value = 1;
          if (map.containsKey(i)){
            Integer val = map.get(i);
            map.put(i,val+1);
          }
          else map.put(i,value);
       }

       for (Integer integer: map.values()){
          if (integer>1){
            status= false;
            break;
          }
          else status = true;
        }
        return status;
}
```

}

Comment: The best way to check for repetitive elements is to use HashMap. Because of hashmap can't accept duplicate keys.